# Using JSON to send form data via ajax to php, but FIRST response shows error when there isn't

Tags: php, ajax, json

I am using JSON / Ajax to lookup a product from database to add to cart. I look up, when i click add to cart nothing visually happens on screen and in the console it shows "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" but there isn't an error, cos that code is suppose to add the product to the session and it does cos when i refresh it, the cart shows the product has been added, and any subsequent products i add after the first i never get this error. Just for the first product (if cart is empty).. can anyone shed some light please.. I have shown the code i am using below..

JSON / AJAX Code:

```
$("form#addtocartform").submit(function( event ){


price = $("#price").val();
model = $("#model").val();
serial = $("#serialno").val();
stockid = $("#stock_id").val();



$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "ajax/addProductToBasket.php?action=add&price="+price+"&stockid="+stockid+"&model="+model+"&serialno="+serial,
  success: function( result ){

    var json = JSON.parse( result );

    if( json.response.status == "success" ) {
      // Show Success, by closing popup window

    // addtocartline();
    $('#stock_id').val("");
    $('#qty').val("");
    $('#price').val("");
    location.reload(true);      

    } else if ( json.response.status == "error" ) {
      // Display Error Message
      $("#responder").css('display','block');
      $("#responder").html( json.response.message );

    } else {
      // Display Unknown Error Message
      alert( "Just Quit in Life!" );
    }       
  }
});

// Prevent Submit Button from posting Traditional way.
event.preventDefault();
});
```

PHP Code:

```
if( !isset($_SESSION) ) {

    session_start();

}

include('../classes/functions.inc.php');


// Reset Errors
$errors = "";

$amount     = $_GET['amount'];
$payment_id = $_GET['payment_id'];


// Validation Form
if( $payment_id == "" )
   $errors .= "<li>No Payment Method was chosen</li>";

if( $amount == "" )
    $errors .= "<li>Enter a valid selling price </li>";

// If No Errors
if( $errors == "" ){

    $doPayment = process_payment($amount, $payment_id);


       if ($doPayment == true ) {
        $result = formHandler( "success", "1", "Payment has been accepted. (Close)");
        echo $result;   
        }
        else {
        $result = formHandler( "error", "0", "Payment Failed.  (Close)");
        echo $result;               
    }

  }
  else {
  $result = formHandler( "error", "0", "Correct the following errors:  (Close Message) <ul> $errors <ul>");
echo $result;   
  }
```

Comment: Check your `<script>` tags? - I've been caught out where I left it like `<</script>` - If not the error I'd suggest disabling all/any browser extensions that may inject JS into a page and see if issue persists. Ctrl+F (Find) "<<" - Will likely help you

Comment: @Zanderwar Thank you for the reply, I have already tried this as ive come across this problem before ;) but its definately not that. Its strange cos' it only happens the first time and not any other time.. by first time i mean.. when the cart is empty and you try to add the first product into the cart.

Comment: If you view the source of the generated page and try to find "<<" do you have any luck?. That character is definitely there **somewhere** otherwise the console would not mention it. - Also, can you investigate the response of the ajax call through the network monitor (chrome > inspect element > network)

Comment: @Zanderwar solved it. something really silly, i was checking the session using is_array instead of checking if the session is set first.. and changing that has removed the problem completely. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Great to hear your problem is resolved :)